# How do I use postgres 9.4 in my rails 4 application Digital Ocean?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, digital-ocean, dokku

I'm running a rails application Digital Ocean. I used dokku to set it up.

I used these instructions: https://medium.com/@tk512/upgrading-postgresql-from-9-3-to-9-4-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts-2b4ddcd26535 to upgrade my postgres from 9.3 to 9.4. Everything worked out great.

However, when I login to the rails console in my production environment on digital ocean, I checked the version of my postgres by typing

`ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("select version();").first`

and my output was

`{"version"=>"PostgreSQL 9.3.9 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04) 4.8.4, 64-bit"}`

It's still running postgres 9.3

But when I jump into the digital ocean console and run

`pg_lsclusters`

I get

`9.4 main    5432 online postgres /var/lib/postgresql/9.4/main /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-9.4-main.log`

where the 9.4 is the version that is online.

I'm not sure where I've gone wrong but I'm new to this all. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Are you running app server and db server on same machine? Make sure `host` name is correctly set in your `database.yml`

Your `9.4` seems to be running on port `5432`. Which port you have kept `9.3` running?

Check the port number in `database.yml`

Comment: so my host is set to localhost and i added a port 5432 to my database.yml file. but when I pushed back up to digial ocean and ran a migration I still get an error that the jsonb column type doesn't exist (which is why I want to use postgres 9.4). How do I check the port 9.3 is running on? and how do I know if the app server and db server are on the same machine? Thanks for the help